# SSRS Gant Chart, Multiple values

Tags: reporting-services, gant

I want to create a Gant chart in SSRS, how do I handle multiple values on the same line
(Task is Vertical, and start/stop is the horizontal bars)

| Task | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TaskA | 08:00 | 08:05 |
| TaskB | 08:45 | 10:14 |
| TaskA | 08:55 | 10:13 |

If I add the data to the "Range Bar", it will only show "TaskA 08:00-08:05" and "TaskB 08:45-10:14", but it will not show "TaskA 08:55-10:13" (should have been til the right of the other TaskA